# Distinct returns result in proper case even though the data is in Upper case - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the name `'MATT MCANDREW'` in 3 rows under a column in table, when I do a select it is returning 3 rows for that name in upper case, but when I do a `DISTINCT` column for that name, it is returning the data in proper case (Matt McAndrew). Database and table collation is `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS`, and if I add `COLLATE` Case sensitive in distinct statement, it is returning name in uppercase. Could someone please let me know the reason and fix for this, it is happening only for this name alone, and working fine for other names. I really appreciate your help on this.

Thanks

```
SELECT ARTIST 
FROM L_PRODUCT
WHERE ARTIST IN ('MATT MCANDREW')
```

Output:

```
MATT MCANDREW 
MATT MCANDREW
MATT MCANDREW
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST 
FROM L_PRODUCT
WHERE ARTIST IN ('MATT MCANDREW')
```

Output:

```
Matt McAndrew
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 
FROM L_PRODUCT
WHERE ARTIST IN ('MATT MCANDREW')
```

Output:

```
MATT MCANDREW
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? What is the data type of the ARTIST column?

Comment: There has to be a proper case "Matt McAndrew" in your table. Also try using the COLLATE in the WHERE clause. I would be interested in the result.

Comment: SQL sever version is 2005 and data type is varachar(400).

Comment: I tried COLLATE in where clause and result is in UPPER case.SELECT  DISTINCT ARTIST COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS FROM L_PRODUCT
WHERE ARTIST COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS IN ('MATT MCANDREW')--MATT MCANDREW